Remove the space between 2 elements under each other using flex
I have a side-bar with 2 links.
The active route gets a mirrored element in the side-bar like this (see the about link):

What I want is to remove the gap between the 2 Abouts.
Here is the html for the links:
  <div id="sideBarLinks">
            <div className="sidebar-link-singlewrap">
              <Link to="/about">About</Link>
              {location.pathname === '/about' ? <p className="upside-down-p">About</p> : null }
            </div>
            <div className="sidebar-link-singlewrap">
              <Link to="/">Home</Link>
              {location.pathname === '/' ? <p className="upside-down-p">Home</p> : null }
            </div>
            <HeaderSearch />
          </div>

And here is my css for the links:
      #sideBarLinks {
        display: none;
        flex-direction: column;
        gap: 2rem;
        padding-left: 10px;
        .sidebar-link-singlewrap {
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: column;
          a {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: black;
          }
          p {
            margin: 0;
            transform: rotateX(180);
          }
        }
      }

EDIT:
Here is the snippit:


div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
a {
  margin: 0;
}
p {
  margin: 0;
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
<div>
  <a>Test</a>
  <p>Test</p>
</div>




That gap is likely not between the elements, but caused by the space reserved for character underlengths.

Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.  See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

Ok, but how do I remove it?

use line-height.

Will you have any menu items with characters that have descenders? If so, a general solution will not work.



p.upside-down-p {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    line-height: 8px; //adjust according to your requirement if needed else keep it 100%
}




Is giving line-height a value like 8px bad practice?

Thank you for reminding me! I’ve updated my response as well.
